# need to call controller method which return String value from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call a controller method which returns a string value from view, for example suppose I have a controller method `public string Username(string email)`. I want to call this method in view so that I can assign return Value i.e. User name to my label.

So I have two question :-

1. How to call this parameterized controller function in view "public string Username(string email)".
2. And get its return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to display it:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Username", "ControllerName" , new {email="your email"});}
```

If you want to call it through ajax, use 
`'@Url.Action("Username", "ControllerName" , new {email="your email"})'` as url in your ajax request

Comment: You are hero :) Thank you @AlexArt.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code  , also add  [HttpPost] attribute above controller action method

```
 $.ajax({
 // method: 'POST', <-- remove this
 type: 'POST', // <-- add this
 url: '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: { id: 'Parameter' },
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //the data here is returned from your controller action method
 console.log("success");
 },
 error: function () {
     alert('error');
 }
 });
```

Comment: Abhishek, you could upvote the answer in case it was helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

View side

```
@model String
<label>Model</label>
```

Controller Side

```
public ActionResult ReturnString()
{
var user=userName//Get user name
return View(user)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AJAX. If you are using JQuery, this task can be done with the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. In your case the javascript would look something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Username")',
        data:  { email: "some@email.com" },
        success: function (result) {
                $('#YourLabel').val(result);
        }
    });
```